# Groovy/Java process management intercept/listen output

Tags: java, groovy

Groovy has a nice process execution engine and I'd like to use it.
There is a method `consumeProcessOutput` that does all the necessary work. But what I want is to inject my additional functionality every time when `consumeProcessOutput` call `append` or something on the **`out`** instance.

```
public class ProcessExecutor {
   static public void execute(IOutput output, String processName) {
      def process = processName.execute()

      def out = new StringBuffer()
      process.consumeProcessOutput(out, out)

      process.waitFor()
   }
}
```

I am aware of

```
use (MyStringBufferIntercept) {
   process.consumeProcessOutput(out, out)
}
```

But they seems work only for current thread and `consumeProcessOutput` creates additional threads.

So is there any solution to **listen to lines adding** and call `output.addLine(line)` and `output.addErrorLine(line)`?

So far I have only one solution which doesn't work good when error output goes along with normal output quite fast: order changes.

```
  def process = processName.execute()

  def inThread = Thread.start {
     process.in.eachLine{ line -> output.addLine(line)}
  }

  def errThread = Thread.start {
     process.err.eachLine{ line -> output.addErrorLine(line)}
  }

  inThread.join()
  errThread.join()

  process.waitFor()
```

I will agree with a Java solution. But I tend to think that groovy's one has to be more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the convention Groovy uses of reading from process.in and process.err and writing to process.out. The Javadocs should be more clear on it. It would seem that **err** and **out** would be two of a kind and **in** the odd one out.

Since you are multiplexing the process' stdout and stderr into your single output string, you are right that individual lines may get garbled. I do not believe you can use the **synchronized** keyword with closures, so perhaps do something similar to the code below but use a locking mechanism or perhaps wrap the outline closure in synchronized method.

```
class P {
 static public void execute( String processName) {
  def process = processName.execute()
  def output = new StringBuffer()

  def outline = { line -> output += line + '\n' }

 def inThread = Thread.start {
         process.in.eachLine{ outline it }
   }

 def errThread = Thread.start {
          process.err.eachLine{ outline it }
   }

       inThread.join()
       errThread.join()
       process.waitFor()
       println output
    }
 }

 def p = new P();
 p.execute("ls -l");
```

Comment: The problem is with this solution lines are not going in the right order. If you execute some script process where error line come after normal line like a zebra, custom solution will print not the same result as consumeProcessOutput.